# What is the significance of the name John Doe in the 1940's?

Tags: meaning

What is the significance of the name John Doe in the 1940's?

Comment: as opposed to what? Can you clarify what you mean - are you referring to the name's origin in general?

Comment: Why do you believe the name had a different significance in the 40s than it does now? (In other words, more details can help us pin down the correct answer.)

Answer (score 6):

The name "John Doe" is used in several English-speaking countries to refer to a person whose actual identity is unknown. You may hear this in police reports, hospital admissions, forensic examinations, or any other context in which officials need to refer to a person whose actual name they don't know. John Doe (and its feminine equivalent Jane Doe) are effectively "placeholder names" used when a name is required and nothing else is available.

This is not unique to the 1940's, and as far as I know the usage has not changed since that time.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for *a John Doe* in the *Corpus of Historical American* I notice that the phrase was used before the 1940s in sentences like the following ones.

> Mr. Craig could be spared from his office as readily as Mayor Hylan has been, nor would his family be left in want as in the case of many a poor devil of **a John Doe**.
>   The proceedings before the grand jury will be in the nature of **a John Doe** action involving a possible indictment for felony under the law forbidding the granting or obtaining of public office in exchange for a gift, promise or other compensation.

The CoHA didn't report any sentences containing *a John Doe* dated 1940s, but it reports sentences like this:

> Filipino health was about, the best in the Orient: in 35 years, cholera, smallpox and bubonic plague had been wiped out; the population had increased from seven to 16 million, and the average height of the "tao" (**John Doe**) from 4 ft. 11 in. to 5 ft. 4 in.

Answer (score 2):

If anything, its usage to mean "anonymous man" started during or before the 1940s. This is largely used in English speaking North America, as I believe that the UK has a different term.